# Is there a closed form formula exists to count the number of non-perfect matchings in a bipartite graph given vertices and egdes count?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Given a bipartite graph with `v` vertices each side, and `initially, all vertices are disconnected` i.e., 0 edges were in the graph initially, how to count the number of ways of introducing `v+2` or `v+3` edges such that no perfect matching exists?

Any help is much appreciated. Counting each such combination seems very hard and I think that would not be the right approach as the total number of ways could be huge. Any help, topics, links, suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Two questions: your title and body seem to be asking two different questions, so which is it? Also, are these graphs labeled, for the purposes of counting?

Comment: Yes, vertices are labelled, like V1, V2, v3, ...

Comment: My suggestion would be to use Konig's theorem to get a vertex cover, and then sum over edge configurations. It seems like it would have two or three nested sums though.